# how to use css in select option on php

Tags: php, css

I use php with ajax POST,

When i click some button ajax post function run, and then 
php code run.

My php code is here

```
...
 <select name='dayval' style="width:30%">123
<option value=''>-- CHOOSE --</option>

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("103.22.222.228","dbtjd1","mypasswd","DB");
    $query = "SELECT Day FROM hashdb WHERE CarID = '".$var2."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      if($row['Day'] >= $day_start && $row['Day'] < $day_finish){
            $field = $row['Day'];
            echo "<option id=list_first style ='width:200px; height:300px;' value=".htmlspecialchars($field).">".htmlspecialchars($field)."</option>";

       }
   }
?>
</select>
...
```

And i tried to run select option with css

By adding css code on html or this code

But it's not work .

Maybe i did it wrong, i don't know how to add css code on here

Could you help me ...?!

Comment: You can't really style `option` except for I believe font size and color

Comment: check this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this and it's working for me. It styles the options and changes their color to red.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR DB NAME', 'USER NAME', 'PASSWORD');
$sql= "SELECT Day FROM hashdb WHERE CarID = '".$var2."'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$days= $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<select name='dayval' style="width:30%">123
<label> <span>--CHOOSE--</span></label>
<?php foreach($days as $day): ?>
<option value="<?= $day['Day']; ?>" style="color: red;"<?=$day['Day'];?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```